# Variable is not incorporating in SQLite select statement Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm asking the user for the budget price and will be assigning that value to a variable. I plan to use the variable in the SELECT statement in SQLite. After the user types in the number, the program raises an error in which the number is out of bounds from an earlier function.

```
    def display_data_condition(connection):
        prices = float(input('What is your budget? '))
        cursor = connection.execute('SELECT Title, Price FROM Book WHERE Price <= (?)', prices)
        print("{:<10} {:<10}".format('Book Title', 'Number of Copies Available'))
        for row in cursor:
            print("{:<10} {:<10}", row[1], row[4])
        print('')
    

    def display_statements(connection):
        while True:
            try:
                print('Display Options')
                print('1) Display data')
                print('2) Display Data Based on a Condition')
                print('3) Display the total number of books written by each author')
                print('4) Display the average price of all books in the inventory')
                print('5) Display the title of the book that has the most number of copies')
                print('6) Return to Menu')
                print('')
                choice = int(input('Which display option would you like to use? '))
                if 1 < choice > 6:
                    raise ValueError
                if choice == 1:
                    display_all_data(connection)
                elif choice == 2:
                    display_data_condition(connection)
                elif choice == 3:
                    display_number_books_by_author(connection)
                elif choice == 4:
                    display_average_price(connection)
                elif choice == 5:
                    book_most_number_of_copies(connection)
                elif choice == 6:
                    return
            except ValueError:
                print('Incorrect User Input. Please enter a number between 1 and 6')
```

I commented out the select statements and cursor printing in the display_data_condition function and it seemed to work as appropiate.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact error message and stacktrace. Have you also tried running your code with different inputs? If so, which were these and did they all lead to the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query `SELECT Title, Price FROM Book....` selects two columns. Therefore `row` has 2 elements, `row[0]` being Title and `row[1]` being Price. There is no `row[4]`